# "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho uma classe simples que executa um insert num banco de dados MySql da seguinte maneira:

```
$db = new db();
$db->exec2([0=>["Brasil","BRA","BR"]]);
```

Na classe db tenho a seguinte lista de queries :

```
$arrInitDefault["queries3"] = [
              0=>["INSERT INTO countries (name, iso3_code, iso2_code, created_at)","VALUES (?,?,?,NOW())"],
              1=>["INSERT INTO provinces (fk_country, name, uf, created_at)","VALUES (?,?,?,NOW())"],
              2=>["INSERT INTO cities (fk_province, name, geocodeBr,created_at)","VALUES (?,?,?,NOW())"],
        ];
```

Essa é a função que insere os valores:

```
public function exec2(array  $param = NULL) {

        try {            
                $k= key($param);
                $arrInsertValues = $param[$k];
                $arrSql = self::$queries3[$k];
                self::$sql = $arrSql[0];
                $arrPDO = $arrSql[1];
                xdebug_break();

                $stmt = self::$conn->prepare(self::$sql);

                //Funciona
                $stmt->bindValue(1,"Brasil",PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindValue(2,"BRA",PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindValue(3,"BR",PDO::PARAM_STR);

                //Nao Funciona
                foreach ($arrInsertValues as $k=>$v) {
                    $pdov = "PDO::".$arrPDO[$k+1];
                    $val=$arrInsertValues[$k];
                    $a=$k+1;
                    $b=$val;
                    $c=$pdov;
                    #$stmt->bindValue($k+1,$val,$pdov);
                    $stmt->bindValue($a,"$b",$c);
                }

                self::$conn->beginTransaction(); 

                if($stmt->execute()){                
                    $id= self::$conn->lastInsertId(); 
                    self::$conn->commit(); 
                    return $id;
                }
                else{
                    return FALSE;
                }
        }// End of try
        catch (PDOException $e) {//If had some error. The PDO object ($this->conn) could not be created. Throw an error. 
                self::$exceptionObjc = $e;  
                //self::saveLogMsgInDb(["exceptionObjc"=>self::$exceptionObjc,"sql"=>self::$sql]);
                self::$arrCatchConnResult = self::saveLogMsg(["exceptionObjc"=>self::$exceptionObjc,"sql"=>self::$sql]);
                self::$conn = null;
                if (self::$die) {
                    $msg = self::$arrCatchConnResult["displayMsgHTML"];
                    die($msg);
                }
        }


    }
```

O fato é que se eu usar dessa maneira vai funcionar:

```
//Funciona
$stmt->bindValue(1,"Brasil",PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2,"BRA",PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(3,"BR",PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Mas seu usar dessa maneira não funciona

```
//Nao Funciona
foreach ($arrInsertValues as $k=>$v) {
    $pdov = "PDO::".$arrPDO[$k+1];
    $val=$arrInsertValues[$k];
    $a=$k+1;
    $b=$val;
    $c=$pdov;
    #$stmt->bindValue($k+1,$val,$pdov);
    $stmt->bindValue($a,"$b",$c);
}
```

Verifico os valores `$a`,`$b`,`$c` e são extamente iguais aos usados na parte que funciona (no caso em que eu insiro os valores diretamente)

O erro que recebo é :`"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound"`.

Alguém tem sabe dizer pq não funciona usando o foreach?

Comment: Quais são os valores do array `$queries3`? Provavelmente o problema está na linha `$pdov = "PDO::".$arrPDO[$k+1];`, isso é uma string e método `bindValue` necessita de uma constante como 3º parâmetro. Dentro do foreach tente algo como `$stmt->bindValue($a,"$b",PDO::$arrPDO[$k+1]);`

Comment: opa Filipe, eu corrigi o meu post. Escrevi array $arrInitDefault["queries2"] mas na verdade era $arrInitDefault["queries3"]. E eu ja descobri onde esta o erro. Dentro do foreach o pdo esta entrando como uma string. E  o pdo nao pode ser uma string pois [[e um metodo abstrato q vai retornar um valor. Valeu. Vc acertou

Comment: marca la sua resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o problema está na seguinte linha:

```
$pdov = "PDO::".$arrPDO[$k+1];
```

Isso é uma string e método [bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) necessita de um inteiro como 3º parâmetro. O valor pode ser obtido através de uma [contante](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) do `PDO`.

A sua variável `$pdov` não está acesando a constante do `PDO`, ao invés disso você apenas está criando uma string cujo o resultado será a concatenação da string `PDO::` com o resultado da operação `$arrPDO[$k+1]`.

Dentro do foreach tente algo como:

```
$stmt->bindValue($a,"$b",PDO::$arrPDO[$k+1]);
```

PHP permite invocar métodos ou propriedades estáticos e constantes utilizando variáveis, dessa maneira (sem aspas e sem concatenação):

```
$a = "PARAM_INT";
$b = PDO::$a;
```